# How to return a spreadsheet which has list of widgets from a build in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to return a list of Widgets(ElevatedButton(s)) enclosed in spreadsheet operator from the build method of a widget but the build wants a proper widget and the IDE is throwing an error on spreadsheet operator that "Expected an Identifier".

The recieving class :-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'question.dart';
import 'answer.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List questionList;
  final int questionIndex;
  final changeQuestion;
  Quiz(this.questionList, this.questionIndex, this.changeQuestion);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(questionList, questionIndex),
        Answer(questionList, questionIndex, changeQuestion),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

^^^Here Answer is receiving arguments for the sending class.

The returning Class:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final List questionList;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function changeQuestion;
  Answer(this.questionList, this.questionIndex, this.changeQuestion);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...(questionList[questionIndex]["answer"] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((e) {
          return ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => changeQuestion(e["point"] as int),
            child: Text(e["text"] as String),
          );
        },);
  }
}
```

the spreadsheet operator(...) is saying "Expected an identifier".

Comment: `return Row(children: [...your code]);`

Answer (score 1):

The build method of a widget expects a single widget to be returned. You are trying to return a list of widgets.

A solution would be to wrap your answer widget inside a `Column`. The column widget expects a list of widgets. You can use it like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final List questionList;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function changeQuestion;
  Answer(this.questionList, this.questionIndex, this.changeQuestion);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Colunm(
       children: (questionList[questionIndex]["answer"] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((e) {
          return ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => changeQuestion(e["point"] as int),
            child: Text(e["text"] as String),
         );
       }),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want the buttons horizontally stacked you can use a `Row` instead of a column, or even better you can use a `Wrap`. [For which you can see more detail here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)

### Spread operator

The [spread operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator) is meant to insert a list into another list. You can use it like this:

```dart
var list = [1, 2, 3];
var list2 = [0, ...list];
assert(list2.length == 4);
```

It can be used inside your widget tree. It is especial useful if you have a `Column` (or other widget that accepts multiple children), and combine it with a if operator:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Text('Some widget'),

    // These three widgets are only added if the condition is true
    if(someCondition) ...[ 
      Spacer(),
      Text('Multiple added wigets'),
      Spacer(),
    ],

    Text('After widget'),
  ]
)
```